# Completely center form in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I've been trying to do is center the form (and the two icons beside it) dead center in the navbar.

I've used the below CSS property, however, it doesn't center it precisely.

```
text-align: center;
```

If you check in the JSFiddle below, it's not precisely in the center. Also, it's important to know that the length of the text in both buttons on the right will vary.

http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5763/

How can I center the form (with the two icons) in navbar, noting that the length of the button's text can change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it, however you'll need to set a width for the `.center-form` box.

**CSS**

```
.center-form {
width: 250px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.center-form {margin: auto;
              width: 245px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a **specified width**. Else the `margin: 0 auto;` doesn't work.

```
.center-form {
    width: 250px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Bear in mind that this is shorthand for `margin: 0 auto 0 auto`, since the sides are counted clockwise from the top.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css class which u want to put in center.

```
 /* Internet Explorer 10 */
 display:-ms-flexbox;
 -ms-flex-pack:center;
 -ms-flex-align:center;

 /* Firefox */
 display:-moz-box;
 -moz-box-pack:center;
 -moz-box-align:center;

 /* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
 display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

[JSfiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/5773/)

```
.container{
width:100%;
}

.center-form{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

added width:100% to .container and margin: 0 auto, to .center-form

Answer (score 0):

You can use that code:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: gray;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.top-margin {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.center-form {
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```